# bash: colorize second column of output

Tags: text-processing, colors

let's say, I have following output from ls:

```
$ ls -lAhF /bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 905K Apr 10  2010 bash*
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  31K Dec 26  2011 bunzip2*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 505K Nov 15  2010 busybox*
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root  31K Dec 26  2011 bzcat*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 Jun 24  2012 bzcmp -> bzdiff*
...
```

I am looking for a way, how I could colorize the second column. I know how to use sed to colorize any pattern, but I don't know how to colorize specific column. Basically, I need to insert `'\033[0;31m'` after the first space and `'\033[0m'` infront of the the second space.  Or perhaps there is much more elegant way ?

Comment: ugly: `ls --color -l | sed -e $'s/  *[^ ]* /\033[0;31m&\033[0m/'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU `grep` provided it has been build with [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) support:

```
ls -l | GREP_COLORS='mt=1;41;37' grep --color -P '^\S+\s+\K\S+'
```

With `sed`:

```
on=$(tput setaf 7; tput setab 1; tput bold) off=$(tput sgr0)
ls -l | sed "s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/$on&$off/2"
```

Note that using `setaf` assumes the terminal supports ANSI colour escape sequences, so you might as well hard code it, which would make it less verbose as well. Here with `ksh93` (also `bash` and `zsh`) syntax:

```
on=$'\e[1;47;37m' off=$'\e[m'
```

To generalise to the n<sup>th</sup> column:

```
n=5

GREP_COLORS='mt=1;41;37' grep --color -P "^(\S+\s+){$(($n-1))}\K\S+"

sed "s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/$on&$off/$n"
```

#### References

- [tput - usage, setaf, and colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tput#Usage)
- [Bash Prompt HOWTO - 6.5. Colours and Cursor Movement With tput](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html)
- [Bash Prompt HOWOT - 6.1. Colours](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html)

Comment: `grep -P` is fantastic. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
awk -v on="$(tput bold)" -v off="$(tput rmso)" '{ $2=on $2 off }; 1'
```

Edit: use the proper `tput` subcommands.

Comment: Setting `$1` will break the column alignment though.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `rmso` is to cancel `smso` though (stand-out mode), not `bold`. On many terminals (`tput rmso` does **not** cancel `tput bold`).