# Highlight nth column of ps output

Tags: bash, sed, colors, ps, text-formatting

I'm trying to find the best way to highlight a specific column of some output. Specifically, I'm trying to highlight the **6th** column (which is `%cpu`) of the command:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu
```

I found a [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77173/bash-colorize-second-column-of-output) on here regarding a similar topic, where the accepted answer was to use `sed` to add in the color. That's what I'm trying to go with, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I've got thus far:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu | head  | sed -e $'s/ *[^ ]* /\033[1;33m&\033[0m/'
```

Which highlights the **first** column in light yellow. I'm trying to get the regex working so it gets the 6th column, and just can't seem to get it to work.

In the same script, I'll be doing the same thing, except highlighting the **7th** column (memory). So I was hoping there was an easier way to handle this.

Comment: Oh wow... that was way easier than I thought.... You should post that as the answer

Comment: This awk command adds the colour, but it destroys the whitespace: `ps ... | awk -v col=6 '{$col = sprintf("\033[1;33ms%s\033[0m", $col)} 1'`

Answer (score 2):

In my Debian 9 I have `ps` that reports (i.e. `ps --version` reports) `ps from procps-ng 3.3.12`. The manual states:

> This `ps` supports AIX format descriptors, which work somewhat like the formatting codes of `printf(1)` and `printf(3)`.  For example, the normal default output can be produced with this: `ps -eo "%p %y %x %c"`.

It turns out I can include arbitrary strings in the format while using this syntax. Mixing AIX and non-AIX format descriptors doesn't work in general and the format in question cannot be fully converted to AIX (I think there are AIX replacements for `pid`, `ppid`, `time`, `user`, `tty`, `%cpu`, `vsize` and `command`, but not for `%mem`). Fortunately one can use multiple `-o`. Each `-o` may use AIX or non-AIX format descriptors independently.

In your case the column you want to highlight (`%cpu`) can be expressed as an AIX format descriptor (`%C`). This makes highlighting it relatively easy:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty -o $'\033[1;33m%C\033[0m ' -o %mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu
```

Notes

- I rely on `$'…'` syntax in Bash to expand `\033[1;33m` and similar; sole `ps` doesn't expand such strings. Alternatively `$(printf '…')` can be used to generate escape sequences.
- The format includes a trailing space that separates the highlighted column from the next one.
- This approach allows you to highlight multiple consecutive columns quite easily.
- If the column where highlighting starts cannot be expressed as an AIX format descriptor then maybe the previous one can. Instead of injecting `\033[1;33m` in front of the format that specifies the first highlighted column you can inject it at the end of the format that specifies the previous column.
- Similarly: instead of injecting `\033[0m` at the end of the format that specifies the last highlighted column you can inject it in front of the format that specifies the next column.
- In case you need to switch colors between columns and neither column can be expressed as an AIX format descriptor, you can add a dummy column in between, whose sole purpose is to provide the proper escape sequence. To inject an arbitrary string you need a format that looks like an AIX format, otherwise `ps` will try to interpret the string as a non-AIX format (and even if it doesn't fail, this is not what you want). This means you need at least one expandable `%?` (`?` here is not literal, a wildcard) in the format you provide.

The following example highlights the desired column by embracing it with dummy columns. The "real" columns are described with non-AIX formats (so they could all be impossible to replace with AIX format descriptors and the solution would still work). `%%` is used to inform `ps` the "color switching" formats are AIX-like; `%%` makes `ps` print `%`, so `\b` (backspace) is printed right away; in each case the output that follows overwrites the undesired `%`.

```
    ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty -o $'%%\b\033[1;33m' -o %cpu -o $'%%\b\033[0m ' -o %mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu
```

You can place a dummy column at the very end if you need. In such case the format still needs the trailing space (to overwrite undesired `%`).

- Similarly you can generate a visual separator. Example:

  ```
    ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty -o $'%%\b|X| ' -o %cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu
  ```

In this case the neighboring columns can be specified with AIX descriptors, so it's easier with like `-o '%y |X| %C'`, no need for `%%\b`. However in general this is a way to generate custom columns, even if the neighboring ones cannot be expressed with AIX format descriptors.

- If the output is parsed further (e.g. with `sed`) then remember substrings like (expanded) `\033[0m` or (expanded) `%%\b` are there, even though you cannot see them.

This solution is not portable but I find the code more readable than [the approach with `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283047/108618). In particular when applying many different colors to different columns. Adding a column in front or in the middle, removing or rearranging columns is quite straightforward; while with `sed` it would require careful adjustment of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

**don_crissti** posted an extremely easy solution, just adding the desired column number before the very last closing quote:

```
 ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu | head  | sed -e $'s/ *[^ ]* /\033[1;33m&\033[0m/6'
```

Comment: @don_crissti Feel free to post the answer under your own name and flag this placeholder for deletion.

Comment: This will fail if you wish to highlight the final column, won't it? There will not be a space following the last column, so it will be unable to be selected with the regex supplied to `sed`.